# PHP : Access to Bluetooth GPS via Serial Port (SPP) COM3

Tags: php, bluetooth, gps, serial-port

how can I access to my Bluetooth GPS via Standard Serial Port (SPP) using PHP in Windows ?
Thanks.

Comment: All I can say is "good luck".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a Windows extension for serial data:

http://www.easyvitools.com/phpserial/index.html

This class might be a bit more cross platform:

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3679-PHP-Communicate-with-a-serial-port.html

Then I'd suggest reading about the NMEA protocol:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183

Comment: Thanks for these links ! But I finally create a .c script to retrieve my gps data...