# How to develop Bluetooth based application in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, bluetooth

I want to develop a web application using PHP that will search and store active bluetooth device name and device address. Can anyone tell me is there any bluetooth api for PHP or How can I do that?

- Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691783/php-access-to-bluetooth-gps-via-serial-port-spp-com3

Comment: If at all PHP would only have access to Bluetooth devices in the physical proximity of the server itself. It will not work over the internet. Since PHP is typically a server-side web language, this begs the question whether you expect this to work over the internet in the browser or not.